# NumPy: Efficient way to multiply each pair of 2d matrices in two 3d matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two 3d matrices in NumPy whose height, width is matching for matrix multiplication. (16X3 & 3X16)

```py
x = np.random.random((125,16,3)).astype(np.float32)
y = np.random.random((14,3,16)).astype(np.float32)
```

I want to multiply each 2d matrix in x with each 2d matrix in y such that the result is a 4d matrix with shape res[x.shape[0],y.shape[0],...]. Currently, I am following this code.

```py
xd,xh,xw = x.shape
yd,yh,yw = y.shape

res = np.zeros((xd,yd,xh,yw))
for i in range(xd):
    for j in range(yd):
        res[i,j,...] = x[i,...]@y[j,...]
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without loops? Some faster NumPy way?

Comment: try `np.dot`.  Or use the same sort of broadcasting as suggested for your previous question.  Read docs for `dot` and `matmul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```py
import numpy as np

l, k, n, m = 11, 13, 17, 19
x = np.random.random((l, n, m))
y = np.random.random((k, m, n))
 
# (l, k, n, n) =  (l,          1, n, m) @ (          1, k, m, n)
z              = x[:, np.newaxis, :, :] @ y[np.newaxis, :, :, :]
```